# How to draw syntactical trees with parallel leaves for a natural language?

Tags: trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I need to draw syntactical trees for a natural language. The problem is that I need all the leaves to be parallel. How the other nodes are sorted in relation to the other at the same depth is not important. In practical use you would a sentence at the bottom of a paper, both sideways and horizontal would be nice. The root would be at the opposite side so the tree uses the entire page. Any suggestions of a package that can do this?

Edit: Any tree package could possibly be used as long as it can use an entire page. I think.

Comment: Have you looked at tikz-qtree?  Do you have an example you're aiming to imitate?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not commonly the way trees are represented in the linguistic literature, so none of the regular tree drawing packages ([`qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/qtree) and [`tikz-qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree)) do this by default.

Specifically, the way trees are drawn in the linguistics literature, the terminal nodes are *not* drawn at the same level (i.e. with the words along a baseline and the tree growing up from there.)  So to take a simple tree of e.g *John thinks he loves Mary*, we could use the `tikz-qtree` to draw the tree easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.S [.NP John ] 
          [.VP [.V\0 thinks ] 
               [.S [.NP he ] 
                   [.VP [.V\0 loves ]  [.NP Mary ]]]]]
\end{document}
```

[image: qtree version]

Notice that the terminal nodes of the tree don't line up with the other terminal nodes along a baseline.  This is normal in the linguistics literature, although often when teaching students how to draw trees by hand we start with all the words lined up at the bottom (i.e. at the same level as the lowest word in the tree.)

### Update for 2023

This answer was written in 2011 when `forest` did not exist. For most uses, `forest` is by far the best package currently available, and as one of the other answers shows, aligning nodes on the baseline is easy to do. I recommend [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214657/2693) instead.

**A new solution using `tikz-qtree`**

Starting from version 1.2 of `tikz-qtree` there is now a simple way to have terminal nodes line up, although choosing the value requires some manual calculation. The `frontier` key allows you to specify the placement of terminal nodes using the `distance from root` parameter. So in the example above we can make `distance from root` equal to 5cm and the terminal nodes will line up.  This value would need to be changed for each individual tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[frontier/.style={distance from root=5cm}]
\Tree [.S [.NP John ] 
          [.VP [.V\0 thinks ] 
               [.S [.NP he ] 
                   [.VP [.V\0 loves ]  [.NP Mary ]]]]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

**Another simple solution**

As an alternative to the `frontier` key solution above, [kgr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4535/kgr)'s very simple answer using regular TikZ methods can also be applied using `tikz-qtree`. All that is needed is to insert extra brackets in the tree to make dummy nodes.  So you can simply do the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \Tree [.S [.NP [[[ John ]]] ]
          [.VP [.V\0 [[ thinks ]] ] 
               [.S [.NP [ he ] ] 
                   [.VP [.V\0 loves ]  [.NP Mary ]]]]]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: revised tree]

The only difference between the tree above and this tree is that the terminals have been enclosed in extra brackets: three for *John*, two for *thinks* and one for *he*. For the occasional tree this might be a simple way to achieve what you want.

**An old solution using `xyling`**

The [`xyling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xyling) package also has a way to do this, although its input method for tree drawing is much more cumbersome.  Here's the same tree formatted using `xyling`: (I've left this part of the answer in for posterity; the `tikz-qtree` answers are really much simpler.)

```
% compile with latex + dvips 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xyling}
\begin{document}
\Tree{  &       \K{S}\B{dl}\B{dr}\\             
\K{NP}\B{d} &   &   \K{VP}\B{dl}\B{dr}\\            
\B[6]{d}    &   \K{V}\B{d}  &   &   \K{S}\B{dl}\B{dr}\\     
\B[6]{d}    &   \B[6]{d}&   \K{NP}\B{d} &   &   \K{VP}\B{dl}\B{dr}\\    
\B[6]{d}    &   \B[6]{d}&\B[6]{d}   &   \K{V}\B{d}  &   &   \K{NP}\B{d}\\
John        &   thinks  &   he  &       loves   &   &   Mary    }
    

\end{document}
```

Basically, `xyling` sets a kind of tabular grid to draw trees. This allows you to put all the terminal nodes in the lowest row of the grid and then add explicit branches in the empty cells above it up to its non-terminal node. Since the default branch drawing command assumes a node label you need to use the optional argument of the `\B` command to raise the starting points of the extra branches. A value of `6` seems to do an adequate job.

[image: xytree]

`xyling` uses Postscript specials and will not work out of the box with `pdflatex`, so you need to compile this file with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` The documentation explains how to modify the style file to change this (why it's not a package option I don't know.) In fact, given that there is now pdf support for much of the `xy` package upon which `xy-ling` is based, it would be simple to modify the style file to use either `pdflatex` or `latex+dvips`.

Comment: But you said in the comment above that tikz-qtree isn't suitable for what I want?

Comment: See my revised answer.  You seemed so set on having the terminal nodes line up, that I focused my answer around that. However, if this is *not* actually a requirement, (but just the way you though the trees *should* be drawn, then the `tikz-qtree` package is definitely the best solution.)

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, the extremely powerful `forest` package should be included ;):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\newcommand*\primary{\textsuperscript{0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    where n children=0{tier=terminal}{},
  }
  [S
    [NP
      [John
      ]
    ]
    [VP
      [V\primary
        [thinks
        ]
      ]
      [S
        [NP
          [he
          ]
        ]
        [VP
          [V\primary
            [loves
            ]
          ]
          [NP
            [Mary
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

`tier` is doing the work of keeping the final nodes aligned. `where n children=0{}{}` is applying this to the terminal nodes (which have no children).

[image: forest tree]

If you have only an earlier version of Forest (prior to v.2) and cannot update, you will need this code instead:

```
\documentclass[standalone, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand*\primary{\textsuperscript{0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    where n children=0{tier=terminal}{},
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
  }
  [S
    [NP
      [John
      ]
    ]
    [VP
      [V\primary
        [thinks
        ]
      ]
      [S
        [NP
          [he
          ]
        ]
        [VP
          [V\primary
            [loves
            ]
          ]
          [NP
            [Mary
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would advice to use the [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) package. Have a look in the [documentation](http://media.texample.net/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2010-09-28.pdf) , pp. 475 for "normal trees", and pp. 386, for "mindmap-like trees".

Comment: I would like to see how the `tikz` tree methods can actually construct the tree as described by Algific.  If not, then existing tree packages for drawing linguistic trees are far better for this purpose than `tikz` alone.

Comment: You have some example [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/). With some adaptation in the code, the kind of trees @Algific wants are feasible.

Comment: I do agree with @Alan; I didn't know about the [qtree](http://www.isi.edu/~chiang/software/texmf/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf) and [xyling](http://ctan.org/pkg/xyling) packages, with what I see in their manuals, that's certainly the best solutions for the @Algific problem.

Comment: However, I would recommend qtree, as it seems it works with pdflatex while xyling don't.

Comment: @Speredenn Being a syntactician, I draw trees *a lot* and am quite familiar with all of the methods for tree drawing, including TikZ.  I don't think TiKZ tree methods (including tikz-qtree or plain qtree) can replicate what Algific wants, since they depend on the concept of a hierarchical level. Assuming a tree of *n* levels, Algific wants the terminal nodes of nodes at level *k < n* to be at level *n*.  I don't think TiKZ can do this without a lot of hacking.

Comment: @Alan: I do agree - you're right, it would need some hacking, at least. But, it's so much a pity to lose all the nice improvements coming from pdflatex to come back to dvi (hyperref, etc...)! Isn't there a solution to use xyling with pdflatex without using conversion from dvi to pdf?

Comment: @Speredenn Yes, as I mention in my answer, there is information about modifying `xyling` to be usable with pdflatex. Unfortunately it hasn't been made into automatic detection using the `ifpdf` package (which would be quite trivial to do.)

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite easy to do in tikz so long as you don't mess with node heights on an individual basis.  <s>(So mixing multiline and single-line nodes in the same tree will break this).</s> (see comment.)  Just add extra childs:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[sibling distance=2.5cm,level distance=1.2cm,edge from parent   path={(\tikzparentnode.south) --
(\tikzchildnode.north)}, inner sep=1.5pt]
\node {S}
  child {node {NP}
    child {child {child {child {node {\textit{John}}}}}}}
  child {node {VP}
    child {node {V}
      child {child {child {node {\textit{thinks}}}}}}
    child {node {S}
      child {node {NP}
        child {child {node {\textit{he}}}}}
      child {node {VP}
        child {node {V}
          child {node {\textit{loves}}}}
        child {node {NP}
          child {node {\textit{Mary}}}}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong! I tested a multiline node created using "text width" at a small value and it still works, guess in an earlier test I had "anchor" set oddly.

Comment: Thanks! This idea will also work with tikz-qtree but with a simpler syntax.  I never thought of doing it this way. I'll add to my answer based on your idea.

Comment: great, yeah I was wondering if this would extend to tikz-qtree.  (I don't really use it myself, so wasn't sure what the right syntax to try would be.)