# On syllabic trees

Tags: trees, linguistics

I have to typeset some syllabic trees. They look like this:

[image: A simple syllabic tree]

I’m currently using the `qtree` package to typeset them, but I can’t figure out how to put all the last letters on the same level — like the red letters in the image above.

Here’s a code excerpt:

```
\Tree[.$\sigma$ [.A \ipa{Z} ] [.R [.N \ipa{e} ] [.Co N ] ] ]
```

And the output:

[image: Output]

So, /ʒ/, /e/ and /N/ should be on the same level. Is that possible? I have no problem migrating to TikZ — I only think that `qtree` is a more straightforward approach.

Just to make things clear, `\ipa` is a shorthand I created through `\newcommand` for `\textipa` , provided by the Rei Fukui’s fantastic [`tipa`](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.l.u-tokyo.ac.jp%2F~fkr%2Ftipa%2Ftipaman.pdf&rct=j&q=tipaman&ei=65oITonTJYi30AGn8e27Cw&usg=AFQjCNHPUpB4kxRE1ZgFrWUzM1P-pNE8NA&sig2=kjbDuPrrUXwpLQuPBewfyg&cad=rja) package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17600/how-to-draw-syntactical-trees-with-parallel-leafs-for-a-natural-language/17910#17910), there are both tikz and tikz-qtree solutions there; this turns out to be very simple to do once you know the trick.  Here's Alan Munn's final solution from there adapted for your particular question.  (I didn't bother to try to get the IPA right.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling
distance=10pt, level distance=20pt]

\Tree[.$\sigma$ [.A  [Z ] ] [.R [.N e ] [.Co N ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually much easier than Gonzalo’s answer. I’m going to accept this instead, although both are pretty good. As for the IPA, you just load the package `tipa`, and the command is `\textipa` — but I use `\newcommand` to shorten it to `\ipa`. I’ll add this piece of information in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it is not possible, according to the `qtree` documentation:

> **Line up the text from all the leaf nodes on one horizontal line?**
>
> As far as I can tell, qtree’s design
>   is incompatible with this style of
>   tree. I’d love it if there was an easy
>   way to give qtree this capability, but
>   if there is, I haven’t figured it out.

You could use `tikz` instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ipa}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [level 1/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}, 
  every node/.style={text height=0.5em,text depth=0em},
  level distance=8mm]
\node {$\sigma$}
child {node {A} 
  child { child {node {\ipa{Z}}}
  }
}
child {node {R}
  child {node {N} child {node {\ipa{e}}}}
  child {node {Co} child {node {N}}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that fits perfectly. I understand that there is a TikZ version of `qtree`, maybe it can be expanded to do this.

Comment: There's a simpler way to do this in tikz (see the link to a previous similar question, in my answer) -- add an extra child without adding a node at all.  You don't have to worry about the formatting so much, that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try John Frampton's [`pst-asr`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-asr) package (requires `pstricks`). Used for "typesetting autosegmental representations"

The example the op provides can be seen (more or less) at pp. 26–27 in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-asr/pst-asr-doc.pdf), and at the top of page 8 of the [examples document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-asr/pst-asr-examples.pdf) except it is a more complex representation with the addition of timing slots. Highly recommended for the phonologist.

Answer (score 1):

I just found another solution to this, involving the `\vline` command. Simply insert `\vline` as a parent node under the space you want to stretch (the example below is of a syllable structure diagram, but can be applied to anything), ie:

```
\Tree[.$\sigma$
 [.Onset
   [.{\vline height 3.3em} (C\textsubscript{1}) (C\textsubscript{2}) ]
 ]
 [.Rhyme
   [.(C\textsubscript{$\sigma$})
      [.Nucleus V\textsubscript{1}{ }(V\textsubscript{D}) ]
     [.Coda (C\textsubscript{3}) ] ]
 ]
]
```

[image]

You can specify the height and other properties of the `vline` to fit your particular tree. It seems this might be the simplest way, though perhaps not as elegant as the other solutions. Keep in mind that the `\vline` command and properties should be within curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

To get that syllabic structure using `pst-asr`, the code is:

```
\newtier{tsy}
\asr[tsy=(sy) 3ex ($\sigma$)] |
    \@(0,ph){ʒ}\-(0,ts)
    \@(1,ph){e}\-(1,ts)
    \@(2,ph){N}\-(2,ts)
    \@(0,ts){A}\-(1,tsy)
    \@(1,ts){N}\-(1.5,sy)
    \@(2,ts){Co}\-(1.5,sy)
    \@(1.5,sy){R}\-(1,tsy)
    \@(1,tsy){$\sigma$}
\endasr
```

You have to add this in you preamble:

```
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr,graphicx}
\newpsstyle{bigsyls}{extragap=.6ex,unitxgap=true,xgap=3.5ex,ts=0pt ($\times$),sy=5.5ex ($\sigma$) .7ex,ph=-4.5ex (pf)}
\newpsstyle{dashed}{linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt}
\newpsstyle{crossing}{xed=true,xedtype=\xedcirc,style=dashed}
\newpsstyle{dotted}{linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1.2pt,dotsep=1.6pt}
\def\feat#1{$\rm [#1]$}
\def\crossing{\pscircle[linestyle=solid,linewidth=.5pt](0,0){.7ex}}%
\newdimen\dimpuba
\newdimen\dimpubb
\def\TO{\quad$\rightarrow$\quad}
\tiershortcuts
```

The result is:

[image]