# Lining up leaf nodes in pstree

Tags: vertical-alignment, pstricks, linguistics

I am a TeX newbie, trying to make a syntax tree. What I'm going for is this:

```
        X
       /           X            / \           X   \          / \   \         X   \   \        / \   \   \       A   B   C   D   E
a   b   c   d   e
```

where the bottom row includes some subscripts. My code is as follows:

```
\pstree[levelsep=5ex]{ \TR{X} }{
  \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
    \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
      \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
        \TR{\shortstack{{\em A}\\a}}
        \TR{\shortstack{{\em B}\\b}}
      }
      \TR{\shortstack{{\em C}\\c}}
    }
    \TR{\shortstack{{\em D}\\d}}
  }
  \TR{\shortstack{{\em E}\\e}}
}
```

Two questions:

a) How can I align the leaf nodes at the bottom instead of immediately beneath their mother node?

b) The vertical spacing of the things in the `shortstack` is inconsistent (probably by some sort of "if it fits" criterion - if if there's an "j" or a "g" on the upper word, the spacing increases to accomodate the downstroke). Is there a better way of writing things one beneath another that will always have the same vertical spacing?

**EDIT**: as requested, minimal example of node-internal formatting problem:

```
\pstree[levelsep=5ex]{ \TR{Compare:} }{
  \TR{\shortstack{h\\j}}
  \TR{\shortstack{m\\n}}
}
```

Notice how higher "h" is compared to "m" ("j" and "n" being level).

Comment: See if this question helps you: [How to draw syntactical trees with parallel leafs for a natural language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17600/2693). Unless you must use `pstricks` for independent reasons, I recommend using `tikz-qtree` for this.

Comment: Dunno, I couldn't get in-node formatting to work in tikz-qtree. Besides, this is almost good-enough (if it only weren't for the damn `shortstack` spacing problems)

Comment: I guess the question is how you want the tree to look. As you have more nodes and if the tree has right hand nodes that themselves branch, having the branches project directly to the terminals makes for a very large tree. If the example in my answer to the linked question is a satisfactory way to represent the terminal nodes, edit your question to show a minimal example of the problem you are having with the in-node formatting, and maybe we can solve that.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Edited

Comment: @Amadan: See my answer to correct for this vertical misalignment.

Comment: @Amadan I was expecting a tikz-qtree example (based on your previous comment about not getting it to work.)

Comment: @AlanMunn: Oh, sorry. Misunderstood. I don't remember what didn't work any more, just that I tried and failed. And Werner's example works like a charm, without me having to rewrite all my examples into a different form.

Comment: @Amadan That's fine. Werner's solution is indeed very nice. It's always interesting to see the neat things that makes `pstricks` live up to its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\skiplevel{...}` or `\skiplevels{<num>}...\endskiplevels` you can push nodes down a (or `<num>`) level(s) to line them up with nodes on a lower level. The projection is such that it keeps the horizontal alignment as if the nodes were on their original level.

Additionally, instead of using `\substack`, you could add the contents in a `tabular` like in the macro `\stackit{<top>}{<bottom>}` below. It places `<top>` and `<bottom>` in a `tabular` (aligned at the top `[t]`) with center alignment (and no inter-column spacing `@{}` on either side). Additionally, `<top>` is typeset using *emphasize* `{\em ..}`. All the baselines will be vertically aligned. If you have a more complex arrangement of leave node labels, then other alternatives also exist:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-tree
% A macro to stack leave node contents: \stackit{<top>}{<bottom>}
\newcommand{\stackit}[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}{\em #1}\\#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\pstree[levelsep=5ex,nodesep=3pt]{ \TR{X} }{
  \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
    \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
      \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
        \TR{\stackit{A}{a}}
        \TR{\stackit{B}{b}}
      }
      \skiplevel{\TR{\stackit{C}{c}}}
    }
    \skiplevels{2}\TR{\stackit{D}{d}}\endskiplevels
  }
  \skiplevels{3}\TR{\stackit{E}{e}}\endskiplevels
}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Oooh, `tabular` works great! Although `renewcommand` fails with `LaTeX Error: \stackit undefined.`... Works with `newcommand` though. Weird. Anyway - thank you!

Comment: Sorry, corrected the code now - `\renewcommand` is only used if the macro already exists. If not, use `\newcommand`. `\providecommand` would also have worked, which executes either `\renew...` or `\new...` based on the existence of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like `skiplevel`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\begin{document}

\pstree[treesep=1.2cm,levelsep=0.5cm]{ \TR{X} }{
  \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
    \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
      \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
        \TR{\shortstack{{\em A}\\a}}
        \TR{\shortstack{{\em B}\\b}}
      }
      \skiplevels{1}%\skiplevel{\Tn\Tn}
        \TR{\shortstack{{\em C}\\c}}
      \endskiplevels
      }
      \skiplevels{2}%\skiplevel{\Tn\Tn}
            \TR{\shortstack{{\em D}\\d}}
      \endskiplevels
    }
    \skiplevels{3}%\skiplevel{\Tn\Tn}
        \TR{\shortstack{{\em E}\\e}}
    \endskiplevels
  }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\newcommand\Stack[2][0.8]{{\def\arraystretch{#1}\tabular{@{}c@{}}#2\endtabular}}
\begin{document}

\pstree[levelsep=10mm,nodesep=1mm]{ \TR{X} }{
  \pstree[]{ \TR{X} }{
    \pstree{ \TR{X} }{
      \pstree[treesep=5mm]{ \TR{X} }{
        \TR{\Stack{\em A\\a}}
        \Tn
        \TR{\Stack{\em B\\b}}
        \Tn
      }
      \skiplevel{\TR{\Stack{\em C\\c}}}
    }
    \skiplevels{2}\TR{\Stack{\em D\\d}}\endskiplevels
  }
  \skiplevels{3}\TR{\Stack{\em E\\e}}\endskiplevels
}
\end{document}
```

[image]