# lingtrees on Miktex

Tags: miktex, trees, linguistics, python

I'm using MikTex 2.9 on Windows 7. I also have python 2.7 installed and added to my path. I'm trying to install and use lingtrees to draw syntax trees. Unfortunately it doesn't have a MikTex distribution, so I have to install it by hand. I am using [this](http://arts.anu.edu.au/Linguistics/People/AveryAndrews/Software/latex/LingTrees30.zip) distribution (the documentation by itself is [here](http://arts.anu.edu.au/Linguistics/People/AveryAndrews/Software/latex/lingtrees.doc.pdf)). I've create a local tex mf directory and added it as a root in MikTex options. I added each of the necessary sty files to that directory, and trees.py is also in my path. I tried compiling this minimal document that comes with the distribution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cm-lingmacros, lingtrees}

\begin{document}
Here is a very simple example:
\begin{example}
.[
S
   NP
     John
   VP
     V
       bit
     NP|tri
       Fido's best mate|tri
.]
\end{example}
That was easy, wasn't it?
\end{document}
```

But instead of producing a tree, the bracketed notation is output (minus the newlines). "That was easy, wasn't it?" Not really. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use `lingtrees`? I would recommend `qtree` or `tikz-qtree` (especially the latter) as a much simpler alternative. See e.g. [How to draw syntactical trees with parallel leafs for a natural language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17600/2693) for some examples.

Comment: qtree is not an option because it does not work in figure environments. I was trying to use this because a professor recommended it; however, he's a linux user. I'll investigate tikz-qtree.

Comment: What? `qtree` certainly works in figure environments. Maybe you should post a minimal example of what you don't think works with `qtree` and we can fix that.

Comment: Huh. Looking at the documentation, I see that it is just automath that has trouble in figure environments in qtree. I feel silly. Except that now I've learned that tikz-qtree is way better. I'll leave the question just in case, though. Thanks!

Comment: Even that doesn't appear to be quite true. A quick test shows that the automath stuff works inside figures as well as long as it's inside the `Tree` itself.