# Demonstrating syntax of a sentence

Tags: trees, linguistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw syntactical trees with parallel leafs for a natural language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17600/how-to-draw-syntactical-trees-with-parallel-leafs-for-a-natural-language)

Consider page 4 in following paper: [Pantcheva 2007](http://www.hum.uit.no/a/pantcheva/pres/seminar/pantcheva-Ezafe-DPSeminar.pdf)

[image]

Which package can be used to draw a similar structure? (As elegant as possible)

Comment: Duplicate of [How to draw syntactical trees with parallel leafs for a natural language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17600/2693).

Comment: the subscripts "Poss" and "def" would look better if they were set with `\mathit` or `\mathrm` (not sure of common practice, but these are abbreviations, not strings of variables).  that being said, i also think this covers the same territory as the question cited by Alan Munn.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, that's a consequence of the subscripts being simply `$_...$` and should be as you suggest (upright would be more appropriate.)

Comment: I had seen the duplicate comment, but since there's no `pstricks` answer in the other question, I thought I'd add it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several packages available: [`qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/qtree), [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) has built-in features to build trees, and [`tikz-qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) which combines features from the first two. Here's a simple example taken from the documenation of the [`tikz-qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.append style={very thick}}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
                 [.VP [.V sat ]
                          [.PP [.P on ]
                                   [.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides `tikz` you can also use `pstricks`, more specifically `pst-tree`. The syntax is `\pstree{root}{successors}`, where *root* and *successors* are one of the available node types, e.g. `\TR`, or another (nested) `\pstree`. More details are given in chapter 8 of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-user.pdf).

`pstricks` figures can be compiled by using latex=>PS=>PDF or any of the alternatives given on the [PSTricks website](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput).

Code for Gonzalo Medina's example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\begin{document}
    %formatting
    \psset{levelsep=1.5cm,nodesepA=6pt,nodesepB=6pt,edge=\ncline}
    %main tree with root
    \pstree{\TR{S}}{
        %left subtree
        \pstree{\TR{NP}}{
            \pstree{\TR{Det}}{
                \TR{the}
            }
            \pstree{\TR{N}}{
                \TR{cat}
            }
        }
        %right subtree
        \pstree{\TR{VP}}{
            \pstree{\TR{V}}{
                \TR{sat}
            }
            \pstree{\TR{PP}}{
                \pstree{\TR{P}}{
                    \TR{on}
                }
                \pstree{\TR{NP}}{
                    \pstree{\TR{Det}}{
                        \TR{the}
                    }
                    \pstree{\TR{N}}{
                        \TR{mat}
                    }                               
                }                           
            }
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really not an ideal solution for linguistic trees, since there are much better solutions out there with respect to the input syntax.  A better `pstricks` solution would be [`pst-qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-qtree). It's by the same author as `tikz-qtree`.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the package. The brevity of the `qtree` syntax obviously is compelling.