# How can I add "first second..." ？

Tags: tikz-trees

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(8pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=32pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? See [Horizontal Probability Tree with Level Labels](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185692/42880), [Creating level labels for (horizontal) tikz trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63697/42880), and [How can I align captions with each level of a tree drawn with tikz-qtree?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54970/42880).

Comment: Thank you . But It is difficult !!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `forest`. But if you want to draw trees a lot, you have to sit down and learn how to use the package of your choice - be it `tikz-qtree`, `qtree`, `forest` or whatever. Since you don't say ***what*** is difficult, it is hard to say anything more helpful.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}% initial code from Gonzalo Medina's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56909/
  for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, thick, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    grow'=0,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    align=left,
    base=b,
    where n children=0{
      calign with current,
    }{},
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier=tier #1}{level()}
  }
  [S, name=first
    [NP, name=second
      [Det, name=top, name=third
        [the, name=fourth]
      ]
      [N
        [cat]
      ]
    ]
      [VP
        [V
          [sat]
        ]
        [PP
          [P
            [on, name=fifth]
          ]
          [NP
            [Det
              [the]
            ]
            [N
              [mat, name=sixth]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \coordinate [above=5pt of top.north] (above);
    \foreach \i in {first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth}
    \node [font=\scshape\scriptsize] at (above -| \i) {\i};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: cats on mats]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried. My system says "the forest.sty not found"!!!!

Comment: @YumingFeng Then you have an incomplete (or extremely old) installation of TeX. If you are using TeX Live, you can use `tlmgr` to install it. If MiKTeX, you can use its package manager (or configure it to install on-the-fly). If you have a really old version, update your TeX installation.

Comment: I am using MikTex, My system says "the forest.sty not found"!!!!

I tried MikTex package manager, but there is not forest.sty!! So where can I download it?

Comment: @YumingFeng I don't know anything about MiKTeX, I'm afraid, but there are plenty of questions and answers about it here which explain how to configure it. Make sure you have the current version (2.9 something?) and consider configuring it to install packages on-the-fly so that you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Ignasi's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185692/11232) can be easily adopted here too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(8pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=1.5cm}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.\node(root){S}; [.\node(np){NP}; [.\node(d){Det}; \node(t){the}; ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P \node(o){on}; ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N \node(m){mat}; ] ] ] ] ]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={align=left, anchor=center, font=\tiny\sffamily\bfseries,}]
 \node[above= 2mm of t] (thenode) {FOURTH};
 \node[at =(thenode-|root)] {FIRST};
 \node[at =(thenode-|np)] {SECOND};
 \node[at =(thenode-|d)] {THIRD};
 \node[at =(thenode-|o)] {FIFTH};
 \node[at =(thenode-|m)] {SIXTH};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]