# For a tree, I want add labels for every line of children

Tags: trees

I have asked the same question about four or five hours ago. @Jason Zentz has given me a link. But the tree linked gowns down. It is a little different from mine. I tried many time to solve the proble, But I failed. So I have to post the question again.

Here is my question

[How can I add "first second..." ？](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224410/how-can-i-add-first-second)

Comment: Please do not post the same question over and over again, because it's a form of spam. Instead, you can edit your original question to make it more interesting and understandable, place a bounty on it, etc.

Comment: @Jubobs Be fair: you can't say placing a bounty is a realist option for somebody without sufficient reputation. But I fully agree with you otherwise and there are plenty of other ways of making a question more attractive. (Actually, a bounty on its own is not the best option.)

Comment: @cfr True. I was only suggesting placing a bounty once enough rep' is available. I should have been more clear.

Comment: Thanks all. Someone has given me a new answer, but where can I download forest.sty? I am using MikTex, My system says "the forest.sty not found"!!!!

I tried MikTex package manager, but there is not forest.sty!!

Comment: @YumingFeng `forest` is definitely available in MiKTeX as [its CTAN page](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) shows. Perhaps you have an outdated distribution?